# Sprite Kit: How to make a node "jump" and also move it left or right, dependant on node position and length of touch?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

This is my first post so go easy haha.

I'm new to 'iOS' 'coding', 'Xcode' and 'spritekit'. I'm looking to make an image node "jump" a distance on the positive y-axis if I touch anywhere on the screen, although if I touch somewhere to the left or right if the image and hold for a certain time, it moves in the respective left or right direction, a distance respective to the length of the touch.

Not sure if that's very clear, but any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: please share what you have tried out

Comment: I haven't really done much at all, like I said I'm super fresh to objective c coding. I tried to make a touchesbegin method that adds an impulse to the node to move upwards but not sure how to make it move left right with the touches etc..

Comment: Try Ray Wenderlich's site. He has a tutorial called Super Koalio that does everything you want. And the tut will only take a little time. It will also help you learn obj c, xcode stuff, tons of great info on his site.

Answer (score 0):

You could move a node like this

In touchesEnded: or touchesBegan: method:

```
{
node.position.y += 50;
}
```

In order for sprite to move somewhere you could also use actions, there is a family of actions like `moveTo` action.

I would suggest picking upa tutorial or a book about sprite kit. Good site with free tutorials is raywenderlich.com

Answer (score -2):

Please Try this code :

***a sprite move : left/right according to your touch direction anywhere on screen***

```
  // CGPoint initialPos; // in .h file

  -(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
     CGPoint touchPt = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
     initialPos = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchPt];
  }
  -(void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {
     UITouch *myTouch=[touches anyObject];
     CGPoint currentPos=[myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
     currentPos=[[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:currentPos];

     float diffX = currentPos.x - initialPos.x;
     float diffY = currentPos.y - initialPos.y;

     CGPoint velocity = ccp(diffX, diffY);
     initialPos = currentPos;
     [Sprite setPosition:ccpAdd([SmileBall position], velocity)];
  }

  - (void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {
     UITouch *myTouch=[touches anyObject];
     CGPoint currentPos=[myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
     currentPos=[[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:currentPos];
     float diffX = currentPos.x - initialPos.x;
     float diffY = currentPos.y - initialPos.y;
     CGPoint velocity = ccp(diffX, diffY);
     initialPos = currentPos;
     [Sprite setPosition:ccpAdd([SmileBall position], velocity)];
  }
```

***a sprite jump up: according to your touch on screen***

```
  -(void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {
     CCSprite *RunningChar;
     RunningChar=(CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:10];
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
     CGPoint touchPt = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
     touchPt = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchPt];

     float radian = ccpToAngle(ccpSub(touchPt, prevPoint));
     float degrees = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radian);

     if (degrees >= 22.5 && degrees <= 112.5) // for upward direction :). otherwise you can write only code without ant condition
     {
         CCJumpTo *jump=[CCJumpTo actionWithDuration:0.7 position:CGPointMake(RunningChar.position.x, 87) height:110 jumps:1];
         [RunningChar runAction:seq];
     }
     else
     {

     }
  }
```

Try this :)

Comment: had a lot of errors man. 
"no known class method for 'sharedDirector'"
"use of undeclared identifier 'initialPos'"

Comment: where you got error can please share. i'll solve your problem :)

Comment: i mention in code please  CGPoint initialPos; // in .h file :)